# Get post related to particular meta box?

Tags: posts, metabox

I have created few metaboxes and i would like to show the post related to that particular metabox value.
Just like we get the post related to tags or categories.

Comment: Please provide more info. How about `foreach`ing through all posts and `isset`-checking your custom fields values?

Comment: http://imgur.com/xn6Bwqt ...As you can see in the image through the link i have provided..these 5stars , 4 stars etc will be the metabox text field items in the edit screen of custom post hotels. So if a user clicks over a 4 stars or 5 stars checkbox ..he should get the list of all the hotels post related to that metabox text field value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
$args = array(
              'posts_per_page' => 10, 
              'post_type' => 'post',
              'meta_key' => 'METAkeyNAME', //what I assume you've called a meta box
              'meta_value' => 'THEdesiredVALUE',
              'orderby' => 'ID', //choose to order by anything look here [http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters] for more info
              'order' => 'ASC',
              );

$results = new WP_Query($args);
//    '<pre>'.print_r($results).'</pre>'; // This is a useful line to keep - uncomment it to print all results found - it can then be used to work out if the query is doing the right thing or not.
while ($results->have_posts()) {
    $results->the_post();
    the_title();
    the_content();
    echo '</hr>'; // puts a horizontal line between results
}

    wp_reset_postdata(); //re-sets back to normal       

}
```

Note this is untested code and completely depends what you want to get from it - need more information than "that particular metabox value" !